# DataTypeName in DisplayTemplate is always null

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to access the DataTypeName from the ModelMetadata in a custom DisplayTemplate, but it is always null. My goal is to make a decimal.cshtml template that looks for the DataTypeName and if it's equal to Currency format it as currency. Otherwise display the decimal like normal.
Here's an example of what I have now:

The Model:

```
public class MyModel
{
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public decimal foo { get; set; }
}
```

In a view that is strongly typed to `MyModel` I have a call like this: `@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.foo)`

The Display template (~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/decimal.cshtml)

```
@model decimal?
@{
    var type = ViewData.ModelMetadata.DataTypeName; // This is always null
}
```

I know that it's using my DisplayTemplate like it's supposed to, but I would expect the DataTypeName to not be null in this case since I have the DataType attribute on the model. Is there any way to access the DataType in a display template like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange, it should work. I am unable to reproduce. Here's what I tried in a new application:

Model:

```
public class MyModel
{
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public decimal foo { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new MyModel
        {
            foo = 12.5m
        });
    }
}
```

View (`~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml`):

```
@model MyModel
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.foo)
```

Display template (`~/Views/Home/DisplayTemplates/decimal.cshtml`):

```
@model decimal?
@ViewData.ModelMetadata.DataTypeName
```

When I run the application it prints `Currency` as expected.

Comment: I reverted my work on this from Friday and gave it another shot and this time around it worked! I'm still not really sure why it wasn't working in the first place. Definitely a late Friday afternoon kind of bug. Thanks for reaffirming that it should work otherwise I would've probably tried a more hacky solution.